# Mocha cannot read transpiled @babel/register code

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mocha.js, babeljs, create-react-app

I am trying to implement Mocha in a create-react-app created application. I changed the test script, now it is pointing to Mocha, and I compile using `@babel/register "^7.0.0"`. My `package.json` is as follows.

```
{...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test mocha --require node_modules/.bin/@babel/register src/test/*.test.js",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-app-babel-7": "^4.0.2-0",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "chai-enzyme": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "enzyme": "^3.7.0",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0"
  }
}
```

I have a `.babelrc` file in my root folder, configured as follows:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "react-app"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"
    ]
}
```

When I run `npm test` for Javascript everything works fine and the file gets to Mocha ok. When I try to test React components I get the syntax error below, and it happens when in the svg node in when importing the default image in the create-react-app splash screen. He does not recognise the `<` character

I tried to change many series of configuration in my presets/plugins, using `preset-env`, using `plugin-transform-jsx`, using `preset-react` (instead of `preset-react-app`) I also tried to downgrade babel using `es2015` but I had no success, always the same error.

I don't understand if there is a problem with babel/register not transpiling correctly (or not transpiling at all) or if I am missing something else in the configuration. Could anyone help?

Below the error I get, I think it's from Mocha:

```
/home/user_me/test-mocha/src/logo.svg:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 841.9 595.3">
                                                              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:656:28)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (/home/alessandro/Development/test-mocha/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:88:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/alessandro/Development/test-mocha/src/App.js:2:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Module._compile (/home/alessandro/Development/test-mocha/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:83:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (/home/alessandro/Development/test-mocha/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:88:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/alessandro/Development/test-mocha/src/test/App.test.js:3:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Module._compile (/home/alessandro/Development/test-mocha/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:83:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (/home/alessandro/Development/test-mocha/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:88:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at /home/alessandro/Development/test-mocha/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:250:27
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (/home/alessandro/Development/test-mocha/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:247:14)
    at Mocha.run (/home/alessandro/Development/test-mocha/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:576:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/alessandro/Development/test-mocha/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:637:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:741:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:285:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:739:3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here it was I was importing an inline svg file in one of my jsx modules. Babel did not have any plugin to transpile svg, hence the "<" unexpected token. I get it to work adding the [Babel inline svg plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-inline-react-svg), and changing my .babelrc as follows.

```
{
    "presets": [
        "react-app"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs",
        "inline-react-svg"
    ]
}
```

And it worked.